# Sugar CRM Integration Using Java and Apache Axis

Tags: sugarcrm, axis

I'm trying to integrate [Sugar CRM](http://www.sugarcrm.com) with one of my projects. I'm using [Apache Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/) as my SOAP client.

I got the initial setup from this [blog](http://www.beanizer.org/site/index.php/en/Articles/SugarCRM-integration-with-custom-Java-applications.html). Using this tutorial I'm able to login, fetch and insert data into my Sugar CRM installation.

I'm trying to fetch Leads using the following code

```
Get_entry_list_result_version2 entryList = port.get_entry_list(
            sessionID, "Leads", "", "", 0, new String[] { "first_name",
                    "phone_work" }, null, 2, 0);
```

This portion is working fine, but when I try to add a query criteria as the 3rd parameter, system is throwing an error

```
Exception in thread "main" AxisFault
faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
faultSubcode: 
faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
faultActor: 
faultNode: 
faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:388)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1411)
```

Thank you

here is my new fetch using the query

```
Get_entry_list_result_version2 entryList = port.get_entry_list(
            sessionID, "Leads", "first_name='arun'", "", 0, new String[] { "first_name",
                    "phone_work" }, null, 2, 0);
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've already compiled my axis-1.4 library to [fix this bug](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-2705)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, need to have a query qualified by the module name:

Sorry for my ignorance.

My further searches took me to [here](http://apps.sugarcrm.com/forums/showthread.php?t=21536).

After fixing my code looks like

```
Get_entry_list_result_version2 entryList = port.get_entry_list(
            sessionID, "Leads", " leads.last_name ='LastName' ", "", 0, new String[] { "first_name",
                    "phone_work", "sic_code" }, null, 10, 0);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Arun P Johny's answer was correct and very helpful. I am using Talend Open Studio w/ tSugarCRMInput component. Even though there is a field for Module, the query does need to be fully qualified.